# z-index for two elements is not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the following code which is a simplification of a bigger problem.

Could you let me know why if:

```
.div_A {z-index: 10;} < .div_C {z-index: 20;}
```

why the button which is inside `div_C` is behind `div_A`?

I need to know the exact reason in order to be very specific applying the solution to my bigger problem.

If you can provide me the code fixed (with as fewer changes as you can), it will be really appreciate it.

```css
.button {
 display: inline-block;
 color: #fff !important;
 background-color: #be1e2d;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 10px 23px;
}
.div_A {
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 top: -100px;
 z-index: 10;
}
.div_B {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 background-color: #aaf;
 opacity: 0.9;
}
.div_C {
 text-align: center;
 z-index: 20;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <div class="div_A">
  <div class="div_B"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="div_C">
        <a href="#" class="button" style="">TRY TO CLICK ME!</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: [That is due to `Stacking-Context`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just forgot to put position: absolute; in .div_C

```css
.button {
 display: inline-block;
 color: #fff !important;
 background-color: #be1e2d;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 10px 23px;
}
.div_A {
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 top: -100px;
 z-index: 10;
}
.div_B {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 background-color: #aaf;
 opacity: 0.9;
}
.div_C {
 text-align: center;
 z-index: 20;
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <div class="div_A">
  <div class="div_B"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="div_C">
        <a href="#" class="button" style="">TRY TO CLICK ME!</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a defined `position` setting other than `static` for elements to which you apply a `z-index` to make it have the desired effect. I added `position: relative;`  in the snippe to DIV_C below.

```css
.button {
 display: inline-block;
 color: #fff !important;
 background-color: #be1e2d;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 10px 23px;
}
.div_A {
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 top: -100px;
 z-index: 10;
}
.div_B {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 background-color: #aaf;
 opacity: 0.9;
}
.div_C {
 text-align: center;
 z-index: 20;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <div class="div_A">
  <div class="div_B"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="div_C">
        <a href="#" class="button" style="">TRY TO CLICK ME!</a>
 </div>
</div>
```